# How to pass query string parameters through URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using this:

```
$state.go("/path/to");
```

I want to do this:

```
$state.go("/path/to?param=myParam");
```

But this is not working.

I have tried:

```
$location.path("/path/to?param=myParam");
$location.path("/path/to").search({param: "myParam"});
```

Both of them actually change the url but not updated the angularjs app - since this is not connected to the actual router.

How can I pass query string parameters using AngularJS ui router?
Note I know I can pass a full url path like this:

```
/path/to/param/myParam
```

But I need in this case that it will be `query string` params.

Comment: you can do this      `.state('path', {
                url: '/to/:param',
                template: '<res-template></res-template>'
            })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) $state.go takes another parameter that you can use to pass query string.

```
$state.go("/path/to",{param:myParam});
```

Comment: This doesn't working. I am naming the name of the state the same as the url of it. Does it matters?

Answer (score 1):

Url config use like this

```
  .state('path/:param', { 
                url: '/path/:param',
                templateUrl: 'views/path.html',
      })
```

you get value in controller use to $stateParams

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but angularjs ui router is very tedious vs the regular ngroute made by Angular team. The reason I am using ui router is just because that it supports for lazyload of the view.

Anyway, this is the solution I was found - using `$state.go` and `$location.path` both:

```
$location.path(`/path/to`).search({param: "myParam}});
$state.go(`/path/to`);
```

This can be wrapped for easy use:

```
module.exports = (path, qsObj) => {
    if (qsObj) {
      $location.path(path).search(qsObj);
    }
    $state.go(path);
}
```